# CNN: Why do we first resize the image to 256 and then center crop to 224?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

The transformation for Alexnet image input is below:

```
transforms.Resize(256),
transforms.CenterCrop(224),
```

Why do we first resize the image to 256 and then center crop to 224? I know that 224x224 is the default image size of ImageNet but why we can't directly resize the image to 224x224?

Comment: In the original paper, the input layer is said to have the dimensions 224 x 224 x 3 but there is a later discussion that the dimensions are 227 x 227 x 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps this is best illustrated visually. Consider the following image (128x128px):

[image]

Say we would resize it to 16x16px directly, we'd end up with:

[image]

But if we'd resize it to 24x24px first,

[image]

and then crop it to 16x16px, it would look like this:

[image]

As you see, it's getting rid of the border, while retains details in the center. Note the differences side by side: [image] [image]

The same applies to 224px vs 256px, except this is at a larger resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The output of resize transformation is affected by the aspect ratio of input images when called with a single argument *size* - the new dimensions are *[size x height / width, size]*, not *[size, size]*. I think that running this two steps separately is a way to work around this issue and ensure consistent sizes of input data equal to [224, 224].

In my opinion, for prediction you can resize directly by calling Resize(224, 224) and the final effect will be the same. Of course the borders will not be trimmed, but I don't understand why this step would matter for any custom data.

Link to Resize documentation: https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.Resize.html